# PHP + MongoHQ/MongoLab Auth with admin?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have encontered this problem while using MongoHQ and/or MongoLab, would you help me ?

-Cannot copy collections to another name.

I wanted to rename the collection, but this needs to ensure DB operations, so i figured i would copy the collection to COPY_collection, and then drop the (older)collection.
This isn't working, i keep getting this when copying :

```
Array
    (
        [ok] => 0
        [errmsg] => unauthorized
    )
```

My code:

```
$adminconnection_url = "mongodb:/xxx:xxx @ xxxxxxxx68.mongolab.com:99968/database";  
$m = new MongoClient($adminconnection_url);
$log = $m->admin->command(array(
'copydb' => 1, 
'fromdb' => 'database.bananas',
'todb' =>'database.COPY_bananas'
));
```

Also: this works when using outside tools, so it's a programming problem :|

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the plan you have with MongoLab, you might not have the necessary permissions to run copyDb. Please email us at support@mongolab.com and we'll help you resolve this issue!